# Meeting room network security controls

Tags: network-access-control

I am aware the meeting rooms which are outside the office premises have MAC based restrictions on their LAN port.

The meeting room does have a wired lan segment. what could possibly go wrong since the visitor (non employee) to meeting room (assuming) does not corp user credentials to authenticate and thereby subsequent provision/services wont be available.

Can anyone abuse the network without any credentials i.e guest mode

Comment: Can you rephrase the second paragraph? Do you mean that the visitor area doesn't have any network connection to the corporate network and therefore MAC restriction isn't necessary?

Comment: I'm assuming they are trying to achieve only allowing approved devices on the network, which is the whole point to layer 2 restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many attacks that can be launched from Layer 2 that would provide credentials to a user that hasn't authenticated to the corporate domain ...yet.

For example, [Responder](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/Responder) is capable of spoofing LLMNR and NBNS requests even without being connected to the domain -based on the way NBNS (and subsequently LLMNR) were designed. They are enabled by default in most environments and IT needs to explicitly disable them (which is usually not the case). In that case, without MAC filtering a *rogue* device may be connected to the network via the meeting room jack and obtain network level access, from their there they could perform a variety of spoofing attacks. [ARP poisoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing) is a related attack that could also be performed.

Additionally, abuse of the corporate Internet may also occur if *just any* device is able to connect to the network and receive Internet access.